# Программа требует поставить запятую после слова "шутя"

Tags: пунктуация

«Это наше «Мачу-Пикчу» – шутя объявил водитель.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос. И хорошо бы редактировать свой текст, чтобы обсуждение проблемных моментов не вело к несоблюдению правил письма в других.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, здесь запятая не нужна.
"Программа" явно не знает правила, что одиночное деепричастие в функции наречия обычно не обособляется.

Иногда это правило немного по-другому формулируется, но суть та же. У Лопатина это § 72. 
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=189